# Does joblib optimize deserialization of common parameters or objects?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a function of two arguments, one of which is the same (and quite large) across many parallel calls, and the other is small and varying.

For example:

```
def predict(model, target):
    return model.something(target)

model = train_my_model()
results = Parallel()(delayed(predict)(model, x) for x in range(100))
```

Will it re-deserialize `model` for each of my 100 `x` values, or will Joblib recognize that it's the same object and reuse the previous serialization/deserialization, or will `model` be re-serialized for every call?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: @kabla002 As near as I can tell, it re-serialzies `model` for each loop entry.